# Single Value Total Ram / Free Ram free memory / total memory

Tags: powershell, memory-management, powershell-2.0

I am looking for a way to find single cooked value output of total memory and memory in use.

```
gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem | select TotalVisibleMemorySize, FreePhysicalMemory
```

so far i have this, but i need only the value output.

for both of them.

thanks in advance shay  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem | % {
  $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize
  $_.FreePhysicalMemory
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understand what you're asking for, I think this will help:

```
$memoryInfo = gwmi -Query "SELECT TotalVisibleMemorySize, FreePhysicalMemory FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"
$totalVisibleMemorySize = $memoryInfo.TotalVisibleMemorySize
$freePhysicalMemory     = $memoryInfo.FreePhysicalMemory
```